# NGINX Reverse Proxy Server sending RST and FIN every 5 Minutes of inactivity

Tags: nginx, tcp, proxy, tls1.2, keep-alive

My current nginx setup always kill the TCP connection after 5 minutes of inactivity, i.e no transaction.

I have this setup which requires TLS1.2 connection connecting from my internal network [client application] to public network [server]. It only use TCP ports (not http/https) and establish with a server located at public network. The client application does not support TLS1.2 connection hence the introduction of nginx proxy/reverse proxy for TLS wrapping purpose. You may refer below :

```
             Internal Network                   | INTERNET/Public
```

[Client Application] <------> [NGINX Reverse Proxy] <----|----> [Public Server]

```
           <Non TLS TCP Traffic>             <TLS 1.2>
```

- using stream module
- no error shown in nginx error log
- access log showing TCP 200 Status but the session only last 300s everytime. [Recorded in the access_log]
  [nginx access log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rwIP.jpg)

Below is my nginx configuration

```
# more nginx.conf

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
worker_connections 2048;
}

stream {
resolver 127.0.0.1;
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

log_format basic '$remote_addr [$time_local] '
'$protocol $status $bytes_sent $bytes_received '
'$session_time $upstream_addr'
'"$upstream_bytes_sent" "$upstream_bytes_received" "$upstream_connect_time"';

access_log /var/log/nginx/stream.access.log basic;

error_log log_file;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error_log;

server {
listen 35012;
proxy_pass X.X.X.X:35012;
proxy_timeout 86400s;
proxy_connect_timeout 1200s;
proxy_socket_keepalive on;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:5m;
ssl_session_timeout 30m;

# For securing TCP Traffic with upstream servers.
proxy_ssl on;
proxy_ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/backend.crt;
proxy_ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/backend.key;
proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
proxy_ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

# proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/trusted_ca_cert.crt;
# proxy_ssl_verify on;
proxy_ssl_verify_depth 2;

#To have NGINX proxy previously negotiated connection parameters and use a so-called abbreviated handshake - Fast
proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;

}
}
```

?

After capturing the tcp packet and check via wireshark, I found out that the nginx is sending out the RST to the public server and then send FIN/ACK (refer attached pcap picture) to the client application.
[wireshare pcap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KByKr.png)

I have tried to enable keepalive related parameters as per the nginx config above and also check on the OS's TCP tunable and i could not find any related settings which make NGINX to kill the TCP connection.

Everytime if there's no transaction (inactivity) for more than 5 minutes the session will be terminated and the access log will record down the session with 300s+- for every single time.

Anyone encountering the same issue? I am stucked for now and appreciate if someone can share their insights on this.

Comment: Could it be that the upstream server is closing the connection first and then nginx is just acting on this server side close by closing the client side connection too?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich hi thank you for the comment, reading from the wireshark, the sequence is that the nginx send RST flag to upstream server, then it send FIN,ACK to downstream. both sides are initiated by NGINX from the packet capturing.